# How to filter categorical column based on a list of string values

Tags: python-polars

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar", "ham"]}).select(pl.col('a').cast(pl.Categorical))
df
shape: (3, 1)
│ a   │
│ cat │
|-----|
│ foo │
│ bar │
│ ham │

Now apply the filter:
df.filter(pl.col('a').isin(['foo']))
df
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ cat │
╞═════╡
└─────┘
```

This won't work. I know that expr.is_in([1]) will work, because that's an encoding for one of the values, but how do i say is_in with a pure string representation that will be translated to the appropriate categorical value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a global string cache to compare categoricals created in different columns/lists.

```py
with pl.StringCache():
    df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar", "ham"]}).select(pl.col('a').cast(pl.Categorical))
    print(df.filter(pl.col('a').is_in(['foo'])))
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ cat │
╞═════╡
│ foo │
└─────┘
```

Comment: Small addition. I am loading it through ```pl.scan_ipc('file_name')``` and the file is already written as categorical. in this case pl.StringCache() doesn't seem to work.

I tried to do a `df.scan_ipc('some_ipc').select([pl.all().exclude('a'), pl.col('a').cast(pl.Categorical)])`  but this failed as well with StringCache @ritchie46

Comment: It seems to work fine here (Polars 0.14.19)
```python
with pl.StringCache():
    dfl = pl.scan_ipc(""file_name")
    print(dfl.filter(pl.col('a').is_in(['foo'])).collect())
```