# Python-Polars: How to filter categorical column with string list

Tags: python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe like below:

```
df_cat = pl.DataFrame(
[
    pl.Series("a_cat", ["c", "a", "b", "c", "b"], dtype=pl.Categorical),
    pl.Series("b_cat", ["F", "G", "E", "G", "G"], dtype=pl.Categorical)
])
print(df_cat)
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ a_cat ┆ b_cat │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ cat   ┆ cat   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ c     ┆ F     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ G     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ E     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c     ┆ G     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ G     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

The following filter runs perfectly fine:

```
print(df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat') == 'c'))
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ a_cat ┆ b_cat │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ cat   ┆ cat   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ c     ┆ F     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c     ┆ G     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

What I want is to use a list of string to run the filter more efficiently. So I tried and ended up with the following error message:

```
print(df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').is_in(['a', 'c'])))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ComputeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\GitRepo\Test2\stockEMD3.ipynb Cell 9 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 print(df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').is_in(['c'])))

File c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\charm3.9\lib\site-packages\polars\internals\dataframe\frame.py:2185, in DataFrame.filter(self, predicate)
   2181 if _NUMPY_AVAILABLE and isinstance(predicate, np.ndarray):
   2182     predicate = pli.Series(predicate)
   2184 return (
-> 2185     self.lazy()
   2186     .filter(predicate)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   2187     .collect(no_optimization=True, string_cache=False)
   2188 )

File c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\charm3.9\lib\site-packages\polars\internals\lazyframe\frame.py:660, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, string_cache, no_optimization, slice_pushdown)
    650     projection_pushdown = False
    652 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
    653     type_coercion,
    654     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
    658     slice_pushdown,
    659 )
--> 660 return pli.wrap_df(ldf.collect())

ComputeError: joins/or comparisons on categorical dtypes can only happen if they are created under the same global string cache
```

From this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720663/how-to-filter-categorical-column-based-on-a-list-of-string-values) I understand "You need to set a global string cache to compare categoricals created in different columns/lists." but my question is

1. Why the == one single string filter case works?
2. What is the proper way to filter a categorical column with a list of string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to set a global string cache to compare strings to Categorical variables.  You can use `cast` to accomplish this.

Let's use this data.  I've included the integer values that underlie the Categorical variables to demonstrate something later.

```py
import polars as pl

df_cat = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        [
            pl.Series("a_cat", ["c", "a", "b", "c", "X"], dtype=pl.Categorical),
            pl.Series("b_cat", ["F", "G", "E", "S", "X"], dtype=pl.Categorical),
        ]
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.all().to_physical().suffix('_phys')
    )
)
df_cat
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ a_cat ┆ b_cat ┆ a_cat_phys ┆ b_cat_phys │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ cat   ┆ cat   ┆ u32        ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ c     ┆ F     ┆ 0          ┆ 0          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ G     ┆ 1          ┆ 1          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ E     ┆ 2          ┆ 2          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c     ┆ S     ┆ 0          ┆ 3          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ X     ┆ X     ┆ 3          ┆ 4          │
└───────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

##### Comparing a categorical variable to a string

If we `cast` a Categorical variable back to its string values, we can make any comparison we need.  For example:

```py
df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').cast(pl.Utf8).is_in(['a', 'c']))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ a_cat ┆ b_cat ┆ a_cat_phys ┆ b_cat_phys │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ cat   ┆ cat   ┆ u32        ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ c     ┆ F     ┆ 0          ┆ 0          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ G     ┆ 1          ┆ 1          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c     ┆ S     ┆ 0          ┆ 3          │
└───────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Or in a `filter` step comparing the string values of two Categorical variables that do not share the same string cache.

```py
df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').cast(pl.Utf8) == pl.col('b_cat').cast(pl.Utf8))
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ a_cat ┆ b_cat ┆ a_cat_phys ┆ b_cat_phys │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ cat   ┆ cat   ┆ u32        ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ X     ┆ X     ┆ 3          ┆ 4          │
└───────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Notice that it is the string values being compared (not the integers underlying the two Categorical variables).

##### The equality operator on Categorical variables

The following statements are equivalent:

```py
df_cat.filter((pl.col('a_cat') == 'a'))
df_cat.filter((pl.col('a_cat').cast(pl.Utf8) == 'a'))
```

The former is syntactic sugar for the latter, as the former is a common use case.

Comment: Wow, thanks again @cbilot.  That's really helpful!
I would argue that cast(pl.Utf8) is not an intuitive answer for most developers.  To me, something like `df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').str().is_in(['a', 'c']))` would be more intuitive. :-)

Comment: Looks like `df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').cast(str).is_in(['a', 'c']))` works in version 0.15.13 and you can drop the `cast(str)` if you use global string cache

Answer (score 2):

As the error states: `ComputeError: joins/or comparisons on categorical dtypes can only happen if they are created under the same global string cache`.

Comparisons of categorical values are only allowed under a global string cache. You really want to set this in such a case as it speeds up comparisons and prevents expensive casts to strings.

Setting this on the start of your query will ensure it runs:

```py
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_global_string_cache()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a new answer based on the one from @ritchie46.

Polar 0.15.15 it now is

```py
import polars as pl
pl.toggle_string_cache(True)
```

Also a StringCache() Context manager can be used, see [polars documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.StringCache.html):

```py
with pl.StringCache():
   print(df_cat.filter(pl.col('a_cat').is_in(['a', 'c'])))
```