# Need to explicitly use `cast` when using `pl.col` versus indexing seems inconsistent

Tags: python-polars

In the example below, why does `scores.filter(scores["zone"] == "North")` require adding `.cast(str)` to work while `scores.filter(pl.col("zone") == "North")` does not need casting? Interestingly, `scores.filter(scores["zone"].is_in(["North", "South"]))`  works without casting when global string cache is on.

Using polars 0.15.14 (conda)

```py
import polars as pl

pl.toggle_string_cache(True)  
scores = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "zone": pl.Series([
            "North",
            "North",
            "North",
            "South",
            "South",
            "East",
            "East",
            "East",
            "East",
        ]).cast(pl.Categorical),
        "funding": pl.Series(["yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"]).cast(pl.Categorical),
        "score": [78, 39, 76, 56, 67, 89, 100, 55, 80],
    }
)

# works with or without global string cache
scores.filter(pl.col("zone") == "North")

# works without global string cache
scores.filter(pl.col("zone").cast(str).is_in(["North", "South"]))

# works with global string cache
scores.filter(pl.col("zone").is_in(["North", "South"]))

# works with global string cache
scores.filter(scores["zone"].is_in(["North", "South"]))

# requires cast(str)
scores.filter(scores["zone"] == "North")

# works with or without global string cache
scores.filter(scores["zone"].cast(str) == "North")
```

A related question about the need to `cast` is shown below. Here, using `pl.col` requires explicit casting to a `float` but using `[]` indexing does not.

```py
zone_count = scores.groupby("zone").agg(pl.count("zone").alias("count"))

# converts to float automatically
zone_count["count"] / 100

# does not convert to float
zone_count.select(pl.col("count")) / 100

# need to explicitly cast to float
zone_count.select(pl.col("count").cast(float)) / 100
```

Related question here:
[Python-Polars: How to filter categorical column with string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519899/python-polars-how-to-filter-categorical-column-with-string-list)

Comment: I guess the answer to your questions is "because that's how it is implemented", i.e., `pl.pol` returns an expression that has built-in functionality to be compared to strings while `scores["zone"]` is a categorical type that does not have this functionality - same for the string cache, this exposes Series values as strings which means they can be compared to strings. So what is your question exactly, do you want to know where and how this is implemented in the source? Or do you want to know why? In that case the answer is "because the developer made that choice" I think.

Comment: I'm new to polars but have use Pandas and R a fair amount. With those tools `scores["zone"] == "North"` would work fine for a categorical variable.

Comment: The float example is the difference between `pl.Series([3]) / 10` and `pl.DataFrame([3]) / 10` - this seems like it could be a "bug". The "correct" way to write though would be to put the division inside the expression:  `zone_count.select(pl.col("count") / 100)`

Comment: Thanks. Adding the division inside a `select` makes sense but `pl.DataFrame([1]) / 3` returning 0 is definitely something that would surprise people coming from R or Pandas.

Comment: Yes - I believe that particular case [could be filed as a bug.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues)